# Wait until copy process is completed and continue in script

Tags: powershell

I am watching activity in one folder and when there is some activity I want to remove some other files and copy the new files and folders from my watched folder.

```
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\TestSpace\main"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\TestSpace\log.txt" -value $logline

                Write-Host "Deleting"
                Remove-Item C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\TestSpace\ORA\app\ -Exclude web.config -recurse -force -Confirm:$false 
                Write-Host "Deleting done"

                #Write-Host "Copy"
                $copy = (Get-Process (Copy-Item -Path C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\TestSpace\main\app -Exclude web.config -Destination C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\TestSpace\ORA\ -Recurse -verbose)) 
                $copy | Wait-Job 
                wait-process -id $copy.id
            Write-Host "Copy Done"

              }    

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action

while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

This is fine but there is a problem, the process is running just one time and after that is still waiting.

```
Write-Host "Copy"
                $copy = (Get-Process (Copy-Item -Path C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\TestSpace\main\app -Exclude web.config -Destination C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\TestSpace\ORA\ -Recurse -verbose)) 
                $copy | Wait-Job 
                wait-process -id $copy.id
Write-Host "Copy Done"
```

Comment: check this link to find out how to use jobs in powershell https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/31/using-windows-powershell-jobs/

Comment: `Copy-Item` can't be used as input for `Get-Process`. You should be getting an error on that?!